# Handle jQuery selectable and dblclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I currently have a jquery selectable list set up and would like to have the ability for single items have a drop down for more information. The drop down will appear upon a dblclick of the list item. The problem I am running into is that if you dblclick the item from the start it technically is unselected, yet the drop down is shown. I would like to disable this so the dblclick is only achievable when selected. Here is my code

```
<style>
#selectable { padding: 24px 12px;} 

#selectable li {margin: 0; padding: 12px 6px; border: 1px solid #66CCFF;}

#selectable .ui-selecting {background: #FFCC66;}

#selectable .ui-selected {background: #FF9933;}

#hiding {margin: 0; background: #FFCC66; display:none;}
</style>

<body>
<ul id="selectable">
<li>Item1</li>
<ul>
<li id="hiding">Soda</li>
</ul>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
</ul>
</body>

<script>
$("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e){
    e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable();

$("#selectable").dblclick(function() {
    $("#hiding").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

Also accesible here http://jsfiddle.net/someyoungideas/BXjaS/3/

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle fix it works great. However I am really still desiring the ability to unselect the items and be able to select multiple without the CTRL key.

Thanks

Comment: The only things that it has lost is the ability to unselect the object. I have been running around looking for various solutions doing this as well. Thanks to everyone and their input thus far.